# Message contains quote from the bot when I send it using custom keyboard

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using custom keyboard (old-style, not in message as in platform 2.0) to send messages to my bot. For example, I need to reply with a single letter. If I just press it on my android keyboard everything is fine. But if I send it using custom keyboard in my message in the chat I see something like

```
| Name of the bot 
| Part of the bot's last message    
A
```

Where 'A' is a single letter that I want to send. Is it possible to avoid this visual garbage (lines 1, 2)?
Thanks!

Comment: @ariaby, could you please claify: I see quoting when user replies to bot using custom keyboard. that I build using KeyboardMarkup. But as I understand from https://core.telegram.org/bots/api  reply_to_message_id is used by bot to reply to user's message (and I don't use it)?

Comment: You are right. Does the text above (with quoting) appear in the text property of message object? I'm guessing you are using the force reply option but none the less the original text should not appear in the text property. Can you log the Update you are receiving from Telegram and post it here?

Comment: @ariaby I've posted message here: http://pastie.org/private/6xggkhqwlngbalxhpjsw <SOME_TEXT> is a text that appeares quoted in Telegram UI. So it is not in the text field (where there is a single letter from custom keyboard - just as I expect), but it is inside reply_to_message section.

Comment: @dbg so yes if you see that format it meas the text is being replied to a previous message. This happens if you send a message with ForceReply option, the next message that user sends will be a reply. What I don't understand is, it is not possible to both send a message using custom keyboard and reply to a message at the same time. Are you sure this problem happens when you use Custom keyboard?

Comment: @ariaby yes, it looks close to ForceReply option, but I use ReplyKeyboardMarkup in bot's message (to build a keyboard).

Comment: @ariaby, I checked once again and see that this issue comes just after upgrade to the latest Telegram@Android from Google play and there is no such issue with Web version of Telegram. So looks like an issue, I'll contact their support. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes you are right. I just checked it. I usually work on desktop client so i didn't notice. Good luck with the report! Takes a year for them to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I saw that it is an issue only for latest (for the question's date) Android version of Telegram.

UPD: Today (16.05.2016) Telegram released new version for Android that fixes this issue.